# angularjs directive link function not called from compilefunction

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to access the ngModelController in the linking function.
I am using $compile to generate the html dynamically based on the user options.
as per the docs I need to return the linking function from compileFunction.

but the linking function is not getting called.
[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PymWU?p=preview)

I am trying to restrict user from entering alphabets when type=number.

**EDIT**

```
var compileFunction = function (element) {
        return function (scope, telem, tattr, ngModelCtrl) {
            console.log(ngModel);
            var template = helper.getFieldHtml(fieldHtml, scope.options);
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            return linkFunction.apply(scope, telem, tattr, ngModel);
        };
    };

return {
        scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=' },
        required: ['ngModel', '^form'],
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: compileFunction
    };
```

how to I access ngModelCtrl in the link function.. returned from compile function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace "require"  instead of "required"

i.e.

```
 return {
            scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=' },
            require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: compileFunction
        };
```

it's work.

Comment: oops... sorry.. thanks a lot for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Your compile function already returns a function (that is the linking function):

```
var compileFunction = function (element) {           
    return function (scope) { // linking function


    };
};
```

You can manually invoke your function:

```
var compileFunction = function (element) {           
    return function (scope) { // linking function

       // ...

       linkFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Comment: but in that case.. as with the link function.. will get below param: link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel)??

Comment: @HarishR yes , thanks to `.apply(this, arguments);`

Answer (score 0):

Going by your definition

```
 var compileFunction = function (element) {
        return function (scope) {           //<- This is your link function
            ....
            return (linkFunction);          // not this
        };
    };
```

Also i don't think the scope is available to use in compile function as you are using like

```
 var template = helper.getFieldHtml(fieldHtml, scope.options);
 element.html(template);
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

in case you want to call these three lines in compile function.

Comment: i do get the value passed from controller in scope... so that is available.. check the plunker link...

Comment: Yes that is the link function call not the compile function all.

Comment: how can i access ngModelCtrl in the link function, called through compile function... as i can with normal link function.. check the edit